# Inserting a table name into a string with SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm writing a macro in sas, that exports a file. I want the name of the file, to
be the same as the name of the table in sas. So if i run:

```
%to_excel(my_table);
```

I want the file to be saved to "Q:/my_table.xlsx". Heres what I have so far:

```
%macro to_excel(tb);
proc export data=&tb
outfile=?????????????????
dbms = xlsx
replace;
run;
%mend;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there.  Try this.

```
%macro to_excel(tb);
proc export data=&tb
outfile="Q:/&tb..xlsx" 
dbms = xlsx
replace;
run;
%mend;

%to_excel(my_table);
```